# Automatically fill changelog.txt after each SVN commit in any IDE

Tags: eclipse, svn, ide, phpstorm, changelog

After trying to search for some information about **"Dynamic change of `changelog.txt` file with IDE"**, i found nothing that could help me to find the answer.

Imagine that I've made some changes in numerous files (PHP Environment) using `Eclipse PHP` or `JetBrains PHPStorm 3+`, and i want to commit them into `svn repository`. Is it possible to configure any of these IDEs to dynamically fill `changelog.txt` file in predefined format with informations (Date, SVN Comment, etc...) ?

Thanks in advance for any info which will point to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not aware of any plugins that do this automatically, but you could write a script using command-line svn tools (svn utilities are installed by default on Linux; on Windows you can use CollabNet SVN or similar). You can pull the svn logs and redirect to changelog.txt in a format you desire.

You can also do this in python using pysvn module.

Comment: Usings post-build (and pre-build) scripts is straightforward in eclipse.

Comment: I tried to find something but no luck. Could you, please, post some useful link where I could find useful information ? thanks

Comment: What is your development platform? Windows or Linux? I can tailor the answer accordingly.

Comment: It's Windows 7. I installed the svn command line tool for Windows, to make a repository for my project. There is no interface (GUI), only command line available.

Comment: Which command line tool did you install? If you need GUI you can use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).